# What is regular expression for MACID='string'?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

What would be regex for below text ?

```
<MACID=aaa1-bbb1-ccc1>
<MACID=ghijklm>
```

I tried using

```
<MACID=(?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)>
```

But it is not giving any result. I just want to extract the string assigned to MACID

Thank !

Comment: if all you want to do is get everything after the `=` and before the `>`, a regex is overkill.

Comment: You forgot to put the dashes in your regex.

Comment: Thanks ! I just froze on that for a moment.

Comment: There isn't one "the regex for below text" - "<MACID=aaa1-bbb1-ccc1>" would be a valid regex for the first line, but there are many others, e.g. "<MACID=([^>]+)>". It might help if you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would work:

```
/<MACID=([^>]*)>/
```

However, if you're working XML data, I would advise that you use an actual XML parser like `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig`.

Comment: As an aside: The input is clearly not XML. Attribute values must be quoted, and element names can't have attribute values → `<MACID value="abcd">` would be the closest XML representation.

Comment: Amon, this is not XML. This is just a some attributes that I have used for logging data while coding. This is not an XML

Answer (score 2):

MACID=aaa1-bbb1-ccc1 (with angular brackets) can be matched with:

```
<MACID=[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+-[a-z]+[0-9]+>
```

or using repetition notation:

```
<MACID=([a-z]+[0-9]+-){2}[a-z]+[0-9]+>
```

If you are just trying to match any sort of letters, dashes, and numbers in general, use:

```
<MACID=[-a-z0-9]+>
```

note that there is a dash in there!